# Setting a nsmutablearray to the same value as another changes both?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray called container, and a NSMutableArray called temp. To make temp, i have:

```
temp = container;
```

Now whenever i change something in temp, for example:

```
[temp replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.9f]];
```

It changes temp, and also changes the value in container too. Why is this? And how can i stop it?

EDIT: Ok, i changed it to `temp = [[container mutableCopy] autorelease];` as suggested

Now the problem is that this line:

```
[temp replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.9f]];
```

still changes the value in container.

Comment: Show your code in context. If you're making a copy of container, then container shouldn't change when you change the copy.

Comment: At first glance (with respect to your second issue), there is actually no possible way for mutating `temp` to have an effect on `container` if you really did create `temp` as `[[container mutableCopy] autorelease]`.

Comment: What @Jonathan Sterling says. I'd gues you still have `temp = container;` or something alike following `temp = [[container mutableCopy] autorelease];` somewhere in your code. However a separate question would be more appropriate here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just setting `temp` to share the same [pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computing%29) as `container`.

To get a true (independent) copy of container use this:

```
NSMutableArray *temp = [[container mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

**Objective-C** (being an object oriented derivative of **C**) uses C pointers for object variables (that's the `*` in `NSMutableArray *container`).

And a **[c pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computing%29#C_pointers)** simply points to an **address in memory**. So if you were to set `temp` to the same value as `container` via `temp = container;` you just **assigning temp the same address** as `container` is already pointing at. Changing either of both will thus also change the other. Or more correct: **you're actually just changing one of them**. It just **looks like you're changing both**, but in fact you're **just having two pointers pointing at the same object instance, whch is being changed**.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I updated my question with a new problem, can you take a look at that too?

Comment: @Andrew You should probably a new question if you have a new problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are just referencing the same place in memory i.e. the same array. What you want to do is to **copy** container array:

```
temp = [container mutableCopy];
```